# Acrobat Pro: how to add multiple custom stamps at once

Tags: automation, adobe-acrobat

Is there a way to add many custom stamps at once? Adding within the program only allows one stamp to be added at a time (I have 71 to add). I tried adding the image files to the stamps folder within the Adobe program folders, but they do not show up in the program when I do so.

I have also tried creating a new category and adding a single stamp from within the program (which creates a PDF file in the program folders). I then added all of my image files to the program-created PDF, but the added stamps do not show up in the program.

Really hoping for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have to add each stamp via the Acrobat's UI because each stamp is assigned a unique identifying number (AP), so you can't add them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if by stamp you mean "watermark" but this is an option to add more than one, without replacing the previous ones.

You can add images or texts, at the size and position you want and on any page you want using the "watermark" feature in Adobe Acrobat Pro.

When you'll create a new watermark, it will ask you if you want to replace the previous one or add a new one. You can also save them for later and use them on new documents.

**Make sure you keep a duplicate of the original copy without watermark!**

To my knowledge, you can't bulk upload watermarks though. Maybe in this case, you should add these to your original file before exporting them to PDF. It could be faster.

[image: Adding watermak in Acrobat Pro]